# data-anchor text - Web-scraping rvest question

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying scraping from this page: https://www.scielo.br/j/rcf/a/M6Ck7FmWQvm8nTCWkLBXLhp/?lang=pt

I need to scrape more pages similar from this one, but the pattern is not the same. I could scrape the text through this xpath - `//*[@id="articleText"]/div[1]`, but actually I would like to scrape from the div- class="articleSection"; data-anchor name "Text".

The div number changes over links, but the pattern data-anchor name "Text", no.

I include this image to give some context:

[image: I include this image to give some context]

R code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

article <- "https://www.scielo.br/j/rcf/a/h9fbHLPbwgRVymxmtxNhKJR/?lang=pt&format=html" # link

aticle_text <- article %>%
  rvest::read_html() %>% 
  rvest::html_node(xpath='//*[@id="articleText"]/div[1]') %>% # here I would like to scrape from data-anchor name "Text", inside the div Article Section
  rvest::html_text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an attribute=value css selector to match on the attribute

```
]library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

article <- "https://www.scielo.br/j/rcf/a/h9fbHLPbwgRVymxmtxNhKJR/?lang=pt&format=html" # link

article_text <- article %>%
  rvest::read_html() %>% 
  rvest::html_node('[data-anchor=Text]') %>% 
  rvest::html_text2()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think ,this XPath solves your problem

```
//*[contains(@class,'articleSection') and @data-anchor='Text']
```